# How do you change a website background in relation the size of a browser window

Tags: html, background, browser

I'm working on a website where if the browser window is smaller than a certain size, part of the background clashes with the text. Is it possible to change the background after a browser window becomes smaller than a certain amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the window.onresize event to check the width and height of the window, then based on these values you can set the background color to what you desire.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var width = window.innerWidth;
}
```

This solution may have compatability issues in other browsers to IE and so the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function is probably more prefered:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var height = $(this).height();
   var width = $(this).width();
});
```

**EDIT:** (Example provided)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onresize = function (event) {
            var height = window.innereight;
            var width = window.innerWidth;

            if (width < 500 || height < 500) {
                document.getElementById('Div1').style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
            }
        }

//OR WITH JQUERY

        $(window).resize(function () {
            var height = $(this).height();
            var width = $(this).width();

            if (width < 500 || height < 500) {
                $('#Div1').css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div id="Div1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
        test div
    </div>
```

Please not that when using the **innerHeight** property in Chrome that the value is returned as undefined and so this does not seem to be supported. The jQuery method would be the preferred solution.

Comment: I'm pretty new with html, javascript, css and all that, so how would I implement this into my html webpage? Example?

Comment: Updated post with an example, also noted that the initial window.onresize example does not seem to be cross-browser (I had issues in Chrome) and so that the jQuery method would be the advised solution.

Comment: If your background was an image, what would you have to do to modify the html? E.g.; <div id="background">
                <img src="landscape.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
                </div> How would you go about changing the 'landscape.jpg'? By the way, thanks soo much for you help!

Comment: Give the image an ID (`<img id="Img1" src="landscape.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />`) and use jQuery to find this image and change the Src attribute i.e. `$('#Img1').attr('src', 'newimage.jpg');`